# Php array index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array containing other arrays(sub arrays). I need to get index of subarray that consist specific value of a key. For example. Here is my array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 353
        [name] => account_2
        [ips] => 
        [tech_prefix] => 
        [password] => 
        [id_voip_hosts] => 
        [proxy_mode] => 
        [auth_type] => ani
        [ani] => 526466
        [accname] => 
        [protocol] => 
        [port] => 
        [orig_enabled] => 1
        [term_enabled] => 
        [orig_capacity] => 
        [term_capacity] => 
        [orig_rate_table] => 
        [term_rate_table] => 
        [id_dr_plans] => 
        [orig_groups] => 
        [term_groups] => 
        [notes] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 352
        [name] => account_3
        [ips] => 
        [tech_prefix] => 
        [password] => 
        [id_voip_hosts] => 
        [proxy_mode] => 
        [auth_type] => ani
        [ani] => 1345436
        [accname] => 
        [protocol] => 
        [port] => 
        [orig_enabled] => 1
        [term_enabled] => 
        [orig_capacity] => 
        [term_capacity] => 
        [orig_rate_table] => 
        [term_rate_table] => 
        [id_dr_plans] => 
        [orig_groups] => 
        [term_groups] => 
        [notes] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 354
        [name] => account_4
        [ips] => 
        [tech_prefix] => 
        [password] => 
        [id_voip_hosts] => 
        [proxy_mode] => 
        [auth_type] => ani
        [ani] => 472367427
        [accname] => 
        [protocol] => 
        [port] => 
        [orig_enabled] => 1
        [term_enabled] => 
        [orig_capacity] => 
        [term_capacity] => 
        [orig_rate_table] => 
        [term_rate_table] => 
        [id_dr_plans] => 
        [orig_groups] => 
        [term_groups] => 
        [notes] => 
    )

)
```

What I need. For example I need to delete from the array subarray [2]. I know a way with unset($myarray[2]) but how can I get this index [2]. If I know only [ani] key value 472367427. How to get this "[2]" in var to insert it in unset command.
If I would need to delete subarray that have a key [ani] that is = 1345436(it is in array [1]). Is there a way to search index of array by value of a key.
Again, how to find this index [2] or [1] by [ani] key in multidimensional array?
Thanks!

Comment: In what way are you navigating to each [ani] value? Via loop?

Comment: Loop and `unset`, or `array_filter`. This is pretty basic array manipulation stuff, try something.

Comment: Is there something we're missing? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work (not tested - but you get the idea)

```
foreach ($arrays as $key => $item)
{
    if ($item['ani'] === '472367427')
    {
        unset($arrays[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of  going about this, but `array_filter` is probably the most scalable.  You will need to create a callback function which searches for values you want to get rid of and then use it as the filter for the array:

```
function filterCallback($value) {
   if($value['ani'] == "472367427") {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
}

$array = array_filter($array,'filterCallback');
```

The advantage to this is that you can abstract your filtering logic (and make it more complex) without having to do it within a `foreach` loop.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: This doesn't modify the original array. - Anyway: Well most scalable is probably a `for` loop making use of `each`. And to filter those, all you need is a filter function that - as with your `filterCallback` is called. That would even allow you to skip or break looping which is not possible with `array_filter`. For the *not doing it within a `foreach` loop*, probably a preferred pattern is with `FilterIterator` which is also extremely well for keeping things nicely decoupled.

Answer (score 1):

```
$remove = 472367427;

foreach($your_array as $key => $values) {
    if(!empty($values['ani'] && $values['ani'] == $remove) {
        unset($your_array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the ani value you are looking for:

```
$yourani = 'Your known ani value';

foreach($myarray AS $array){
   if($array['ani'] == $yourani){
      unset($array);
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't modify the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_search` to get the index and `unset` the element like this

```
$a = array('one', 'two', 'three', 472367427, 'four', 'five');
unset($a[array_search(472367427, $a)]);
```

Comment: This snippet does not resemble the OP's provided sample data.